# AFNetworking and storing Cookies globaly

Tags: ios, networking, cookies, afnetworking

I have an application where I use AFNetworking for networking.
The service that I am talking to uses Basic Auth for authentication.
So in my client I use the setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:password: method to set username and password and everything works fine.

Now I should add a "open in Browser" button to the app. But when I call the URL, Safari on my iPhone/iPad will want the user to login again.

Is there any solution I can set the cookie that I get when logging in into the default cookie store?

What I tried so far is this:

```
NSString* authorization = [client defaultValueForHeader:@"Authorization"];
NSMutableDictionary *cookieProperties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"myCookie" forKey:NSHTTPCookieName];
[cookieProperties setObject:authorization forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"www.the.server" forKey:NSHTTPCookieDomain];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"www.the.server" forKey:NSHTTPCookieOriginURL];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"/" forKey:NSHTTPCookiePath];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"0" forKey:NSHTTPCookieVersion];             
[cookieProperties setObject:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:2629743] forKey:NSHTTPCookieExpires];

NSHTTPCookie* cookie = [[NSHTTPCookie alloc] initWithProperties:cookieProperties];
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
```

This gives me a cookie, but when opening the URL in Safari on my iPhone/iPad it's not working

Is there any API call in AFNetworking that will handle that? Or is there a way I can do it myself manually?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Nope, each app has its own Sandbox. There's no way to share cookies with Safari.